# Google Play Console - Deactivated APK still showing as 'active'

Tags: android, google-play-console

In the developer console, APK X shows as deactivated. It was deactivated when I uploaded my current production APK (APK Z).

When I look at the artifact library, it still shows APK X as an "active" artifact. Any ideas why or how to resolve this?

Comment: Give it some time it will get updated.

Answer (score 2):

Talked to a google tech support - the answer was that APK X was on one of the deactivated closed test tracks I have. I thought deactivating the track was enough, but Google said since I could still technically promote it to production, it was 'active'. Installing a new APK (even a blank one) over top of APK X resolved it.